# Obtener texto desde una lista HTML usando iMacros

Tags: imacros

Estoy usando imacros para conseguir el texto de una lista. Mi HTML es el siguiente..

```
<html>
<div class="group">
<ul id="fruit_list">
    <li class="fruit">
        <a class="etiqueta">potato</a>
    </li>
    <li class="fruit">
        <a class="etiqueta">apple</a>
    </li>
    <li class="fruit">
        <a class="etiqueta">banana</a>
    </li>
    <li class="fruit">
        <a class="etiqueta">orange</a>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
</html>
```

Intenté con:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=UL ATTR=ID:fruit_list EXTRACT=HTM
SET neat_list EVAL("var e_s = '{{!EXTRACT}}'; e_s.substring(e_s.indexOf('<li>'), e_s.lastIndexOf('<\\/li>')).replace(/(<li>|<\\/li>)/g, '').replace(/ +/g, ' ');")
PROMPT {{neat_list}}
```

Quiero mostrarlos de la siguiente manera:

> Potato apple banana orange

pero el resultado que obtengo:

```
<ul style="outline: 1px solid blue;" id="fruit_list">  <li class="order">   <a class="etiqueta">potato</a>  </li>  <li class="order">   <a class="etiqueta">apple</a>  </li>  <li class="order">   <a class="etiqueta">banana</a>  </li>  <li class="order">   <a class="etiqueta">orange</a>  </li> </ul>
```

¿Hay alguna manera de mostrar correctamente los elementos?

Y mi última pregunta es: ¿podría almacenar los elementos para luego mostrarlos?